# Inserted script is not working when I use laravel/ui

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, vue.js

I am using a template from node js  (I just use it because I was taking certain course and that was one of the steps). Taking into account what I've been reading in different posts, bootstrap uses jquery. Then, I realized that the script in head is causing troubles when I insert script in other views.

For example.
This is my app.blade.php, and in the head, I put script as a comment.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">   
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts 
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>}-->

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Style css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

And the view which I've been having trouble is this one

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('grid')
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Style css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">NUESTROS PRODUCTOS</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($productos as $producto)
                <div class="col-md-4 product-grid">
                    <div class="image">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="storage/app/images/apple-watch.jpg" class="w-100">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="detail">View Details</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <form id="postForm{{$producto->id}}" method="POST" class="postForm">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" id="{{$producto->id}}" name="producto_id" class="producto_id" value="{{$producto->id}}">
                        <h5 class="text-center">{{$producto->nombre}}</h5>
                        <h5 class="text-center">Price: {{$producto->precio}}</h5>
                        <input id="guarda" name="guarda"type="submit" value="AÑADIR AL CARRITO" class="btn buy btn-enviar">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- ./Product -->

            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    @foreach($productos as $product)
        document.getElementById('postForm{{$product->id}}').addEventListener('submit', prueba{{$product->id}});
        function prueba{{$product->id}}(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = document.getElementById({{$product->id}}).value;
            var params = "idproducto="+id+"&idcarrito="+{{$carrito_id[0]->id}};

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/carrito', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', "{{ csrf_token() }}");
            xhr.onload = function(){
                if(this.responseText){
                    alert('Lo sentimos, ha habido un error en la base de datos, por favor recargue la página.');
                } else {
                    alert('¡Felicidades, ha agregado un nuevo producto a su carrito de compras!');
                }
            }
            xhr.send(params);
        } 
    @endforeach
</script>
@endsection
```

The problem is, if I let the app.blade.php label script out of the comment, my script in my target view (the last code) will not work anymore.

With my children view I want to insert some data in my database without returning a view. I don't get any error generated at all. It's as simple as it sounds, if I don't comment the script in my app.blade.php head, the script in my children view that helps me to avoid returning a view when inserting data en my db just doesn't work, I could change this last one by a simple alert, and it wouldn't return anything, but return a blank view.

If you know what kind of information should I look on documentation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: "Not working" is not a detailed enough diagnostic. Can you better describe what it is you're trying to achieve, what output you're getting, if any, with particular attention paid to *any* errors generated by this code? What is this code supposed to do? It's very important to be as specific as you can, and this may require doing some additional investigation as to the root cause of your problem before posting a question.

Comment: I understand, I'm sorry, it's my first time with stackoverflow.

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning. I'm just saying you need to help us out here or all we can do is say "That's unfortunate." If you can dig a little more and find out the nature of the problem we can probably fix it for you. Just dumping this here isn't enough.

Comment: You're right, I'm trying to explain better in the question, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it, it seemed to have problems with the way I was inserting my script code in my children view. I had to read about stacks (check https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#stacks) which seems to be the right way to insert scripts in your parent view.

The parent view is the same as posted in the question, but I uncommented the script in the head, and put this befores closing body label:

```
@stack('script')
```

And my children view now looks like this (focus on the push and endpush part which is the script that had problems):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('grid')
<!-- Bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Style css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
@endsection

@push('script')

<script>
    x = document.getElementById("alertabien");
    y = document.getElementById("alertamal");
    x.style.display =  "none";
    y.style.display =  "none";
@foreach($productos as $product)
        document.getElementById('postForm{{$product->id}}').addEventListener('submit', prueba{{$product->id}});
        function prueba{{$product->id}}(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = document.getElementById({{$product->id}}).value;
            var params = "idproducto="+id+"&idcarrito="+{{$carrito_id[0]->id}};

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/carrito', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', "{{ csrf_token() }}");
            xhr.onload = function(){
                if(this.responseText){
                    document.getElementById("alertamal").innerHTML = "Lo sentimos, ha habido un error en la base de datos, por favor recargue la página.";
                    y.style.display =  "block";
                    $("#alertamal").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#alertamal").fadeOut(8000);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("alertabien").innerHTML = "¡FELICIDADES! Ha añadido correctamente su producto al carrito de compras";
                    x.style.display =  "block";
                    $("#alertabien").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#alertabien").fadeOut(8000);
                }
            }
            xhr.send(params);
        } 
@endforeach
</script>

@endpush

@section('content')
<div class="alert alert-success" id="alertabien">
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertamal">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">NUESTROS PRODUCTOS</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($productos as $producto)
            <div class="col-md-4 product-grid">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="storage/app/images/apple-watch.jpg" class="w-100">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="detail">View Details</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <form id="postForm{{$producto->id}}" method="POST" class="postForm">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" id="{{$producto->id}}" name="producto_id" class="producto_id" value="{{$producto->id}}">
                    <h5 class="text-center">{{$producto->nombre}}</h5>
                    <h5 class="text-center">Price: {{$producto->precio}}</h5>
                    <input id="guarda" name="guarda"type="submit" value="AÑADIR AL CARRITO" class="btn buy btn-enviar">
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /Product -->

        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```